Phoenix/Elixir: How to render a list using recursion?
I have a db table for categories where a category can be a sub-category of a category in the same table. For example:



category_id
category_name
parent_id




1
Vocabulary
nil


2
Animals
1


3
Food
1


4
Grammar
nil


5
Mammals
2



I want to show this list on category creation form as a dropdown to select parent category.
Something like,
Vocabulary
 - Animals
    - Mammals
 - Food
Grammar

How can I render the list in this way? Or is there a better way to handle this requirement?
In the controller, I am able to get the categories list in the following format:
[
 %{cat: Vocabulary, subcat: [
   %{cat: Animals, subcat: [
     %{cat: Mammals, subcat: []}
   ]},
   %{cat: Food, subcat: []}
 ]}, 
 %{cat: Grammar, subcat: []}
]

But, I am not sure how to render this in the template.
I am not using LiveView for this project.

Here is a LiveView that shows a possible way of displaying this list with the incremented indentation.
defmodule MyAppWeb.WelcomeLive do
  @moduledoc false
  use MyAppWeb, :live_view

  @impl true
  def mount(_session, _params, socket) do
    socket
    |> assign(:cats, [
      %{
        cat: Vocabulary,
        subcat: [
          %{
            cat: Animals,
            subcat: [
              %{cat: Mammals, subcat: []}
            ]
          },
          %{cat: Food, subcat: []}
        ]
      },
      %{cat: Grammar, subcat: []}
    ])
    |> then(&{:ok, &1})
  end

  @impl true
  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div id="root-live-view">
      <.cats_display cats={@cats} />
    </div>
    """
  end

  attr :cats, :list, required: true
  attr :nesting_level, :integer, default: 0

  def cats_display(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div :for={cat <- @cats} class="font-normal text-gray-900" style={cat_style(@nesting_level)}>
      <span>
        <%= if @nesting_level > 0, do: "-" %> <%= cat.cat %>
      </span>
      <.cats_display :if={Enum.any?(cat.subcat)} cats={cat.subcat} nesting_level={@nesting_level + 1} />
    </div>
    """
  end

  defp cat_style(nesting_level) do
    """
      margin-left: #{nesting_level * 10}px;
    """
  end
end

Note that I use tailwind CSS to style with "font-normal text-gray-900" but I use a style attribute to do the dynamic left margin.
I tried using tailwind for this, with arbitrary margin values, e.g. class={"ml-[#{@nesting_level * 10}px]"} but they did not work locally. I have experienced this before where Tailwind did not recognize what they call "arbitrary values" that are computed at runtime.
I use recursion to re-use the cats_display function.
Take care in your approach here. Make sure you have some constraints to prevent persisting "circular" data, e.g. A is parent of B and B is parent of A. If you do this then you will create infinite loops when rendering or building lists. To this end, I suggest recognizing that you are building what is called an "acyclic graph". That is a "graph" where there are no "cycles".
There are libraries in Elixir that deal with "directed acyclic graphs" and using one of these could abstract the problem for you, so you don't have to worry about infinite loops. For example: https://hex.pm/packages/libgraph would let you use functions like this: https://hexdocs.pm/libgraph/Graph.html#is_acyclic?/1 which will make your life so much easier.
Good luck with whatever you are doing!
